# Upload / place certificate in trusted root store in azure web app

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a public CA certificate (.cer) I need to place in the localmachine\root and authroot certificate store.

How do I do this on an Azure web app?

I only managed to get it in the public certificates under Certificates, but this will not place it in the root, but in currentuser\my

The old certificate exists in root, so I know it's possible somehow.

The app runs on Windows OS

Thanks.